# Fetch content from android directory

Tags: android, flutter, download

I'm trying to fetch data(mp3) from my app's directory itself and display in `ListView()` i.e, **path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.MyApp/files**

for which I've used getExternalStorageDirectory() to save my file there but all I get using below code is just notification sounds. I need data from above path only. Guide me

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cast/utilities/bottom_sheet_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class MyAudioList extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
return _MyAudioList(); //create state
}
}

class _MyAudioList extends State<MyAudioList> {
var files;
List? allSongs;

void getFiles() async {
//asyn function to get list of files
Directory dir =
    
Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cast/files');
String mp3Path = dir.toString();
print(mp3Path);
List<FileSystemEntity> _files;
List<FileSystemEntity> _songs = [];
_files = dir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: false);
for (FileSystemEntity entity in _files) {
  String path = entity.path;
  if (path.endsWith('.mp3')) _songs.add(entity);
}
print(_songs);
// print(_songs.length);
setState(() {
  files = _files;
  allSongs = _songs;
}); //update the UI
}

@override
void initState() {
getFiles(); //call getFiles() function on initial state.
super.initState();
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () async {
    getFiles();
  },
  child: Scaffold(
      body: files == null
          ? Center(
              child: Text(
              'Seaching..',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ))
          : ListView.builder(
              //if file/folder list is grabbed, then show here
              itemCount: allSongs!.length, //_songs.length ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  leading: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        child: Image.network(
                          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo- 
       1541963463532-d68292c34b19?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8Ym9va3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80",
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    '$allSongs',
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    "publisher",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[400]!,
                      fontSize: 13,
                    ),
                  ),
                  trailing: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, 
   children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: 
   Colors.grey),
                    )
                  ]),
                );
              },
            )),
);
}
}
```

Comment: I can't even see where in your code you have used your path!... Plz show where you do so. And is it correct that the code works, except you get notification sounds from inside your phone storage instead of the files you have created with your app?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård check new one this does but i need it in ListView format with image title and url

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård Your answer seems helpful.

Comment: Well good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To list all the files or folders, you have to use flutter_file_manager, path, and path_provider_ex flutter package. Add the following lines in your pubspec.yaml file to add this package in your dependency.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path: ^1.6.4
  path_provider_ex: ^1.0.1
  flutter_file_manager: ^0.2.0
```

Add read / write permissions in your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml before  tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

If you still get the Permission Denied error, add the following line on AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

see the explanation in the comment.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_file_manager/flutter_file_manager.dart';
import 'package:path_provider_ex/path_provider_ex.dart';
//import package files

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
          home: MyFileList(), //call MyFile List 
    );
  }
}

//apply this class on home: attribute at MaterialApp()
class MyFileList extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyFileList();
  }
}

class _MyFileList extends State<MyFileList>{
  var files;
 
  void getFiles() async { //asyn function to get list of files
      List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
      var root = storageInfo[0].rootDir; //storageInfo[1] for SD card, geting the root directory
      var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //
      files = await fm.filesTree( 
      //set fm.dirsTree() for directory/folder tree list
        excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/Android"],
        extensions: ["mp3"] //optional, to filter files, remove to list all,
        //remove this if your are grabbing folder list
      );
      setState(() {}); //update the UI
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getFiles(); //call getFiles() function on initial state. 
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:Text("File/Folder list from SD Card"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent
      ),
      body:files == null? Text("Searching Files"):
           ListView.builder(  //if file/folder list is grabbed, then show here
              itemCount: files?.length ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child:ListTile(
                         title: Text(files[index].path.split('/').last),
                         leading: Icon(Icons.image),
                         trailing: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.redAccent,),
                      )
                    );
              },
          )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this seems old without null safety

Comment: yes, check it once for latest

Answer (score 0):

Since `flutter_file_manager` package is discontinued I used it´s code that searches files and the params written before by [Mahesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10791086/mahesh) and implemented it in a file under this repo so people can use it freely:

https://github.com/alaincruz06/file_searcher

PS: Doesn´t edit or sort (or do the other tricks that the older package did), but it´s an updated (null-safety) solution to find specific files on your device with known extensions.